# Nancy Modules are globally discovered, how to implement the same idea with .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nancy

I have a web api project, and I have a HttpSelfHost server.
I know that when using NancyFX you can use Nancy.Self.Host to host a server and then make calls to the API which extends NancyModule, I got 2 questions.

1. How does Nancy see the api module if its in a different project?
2. How do I implement the same idea without Nancy?
   the idea is:

having an API project, and having a server project, how could I run the server, and then send requests with the API routes?

any help\tip would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NancyFX can do that discovering all the assemblies in his working directory and looking for class who extend NancyModule through reflection. NancyFX use an IoC container to collect the modules.

I suggest you to check [NancyFX](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy)code on github especially the [boostrapper](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Bootstrapper/NancyBootstrapperBase.cs) and the [Nancy Boostrapper](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/DefaultNancyBootstrapper.cs) who use TinyIoC as IoC container.

**EDIT:**

Looking that code you should be able to replicate the feature you need.

It can be you need less infrastructure to load classes dynamically.
I suggest you to look at [System.Reflection namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netframework-4.8). With that you can load assemblies dynamically and search the classes implementing a known interface or they have a known prefix.

Comment: So is there anything in the .net framework that lets you do that? or do you have to write all the code by yourself?

Comment: Thank you Lerenzo, ive managed to find a class which implements ApiController, now I just have to see how im going to connect both of them, brain is kinda fried after trying to figure this out for a couple of hours straight lol I can bearly remember what im trying to acomplish. thanks!